# Postgres date subtraction in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to do a dynamic query which always takes an interval of *todays_date* and *todays_date - 30*

```
SELECT day::date
FROM   generate_series('2014-08-01'::date, '2014-09-14'::date, interval '1 week') day
```

But with current date, something like this

```
SELECT day::date
FROM   generate_series(CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE - 30, interval '1 week') day
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it almost right. Try this (for an incrementing series):

```
SELECT day::date
FROM   generate_series(CURRENT_DATE - interval '30 days', CURRENT_DATE, interval '1 week') day
```

Or if you really want to go backward:

```
SELECT day::date
FROM   generate_series(CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE - interval '30 days', -interval '1 week') day
```